# iMessages on macOS showing showing prior sent message in the text field

Tags: macos, messages

Sometimes when I open iMessages on my MacBook I'll find that a previously sent message is still in the text field as though I haven't sent it. It's inconsistent, I don't know how to reproduce it. I'm wondering if this is a bug somehow. Even if additional messages have sent since, it's remembering something previously typed in the field (as though it's caching it). Any ideas on how to prevent?

Comment: This might be due to incomplete syncing. Turn off low power mode on iPhone, Turn on Wi-Fi on iPhone. Test syncing by sending a dummy message from Mac. See if it still happens.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii I don't have Low Power Mode on for my iPhone, and it's always connected to Wi-Fi at home. Not sure why syncing would should later show a previously sent message still in the iMessage text field as though it hadn't been sent.